# LaTeX3: how to check if a file exists and if a macro does not exist?

Tags: latex3

I wanted to check if a file exists and a macro does not exist, and execute code A in that case and code B in the other case. Unfortunately, `\file_if_exist_p:N` does not exist, so I cannot write:

```
\bool_if:NTF {\file_if_exist_p:x {\myfile} || !(\cs_if_exist_p:N {\myMacro}) } {
  code A
} {
  code B
}
```

I'm sure I can do a dirty fix by nesting two conditions `\cs_if_exist` and `\file_if_exist` and duplicating `code A` (or possibly defining in a macro before), or defining a macro in these nested conditions and check after if the macro exists or not… but all of this seems really dirty. Is there a clean way to solve this issue?

I tried to output directly the true or false boolean in the condition, without success (this gives an error message):

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\begin{document}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\def\myfile{myfile.txt}
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \file_if_exist:nTF { xTF }

\bool_if:nTF {
  (\file_if_exist:xTF {\myfile} {\c_true_bool} {\c_false_bool})
  || !(\cs_if_exist_p:N {\myMacro}) }
{
  The~file~exists
} {
  I~need~to~recreate~the~file
}  

\ExplSyntaxOff
\end{document}
```

Comment: Currently, `\file_if_exist:nTF` is not expandable, so can't be used in a predicate: I'm discussing this with the team as it's possible we could alter this

Comment: As an aside: I'd suggest using `\bool_lazy_and:nnTF` or `\bool_lazy_or:nnTF` (depending which you need) instead of `\bool_if:nTF` if you need only two checks.

Comment: But why not nesting the conditions if it is the only working possibility right now? Is it really that dirty? Maybe it is, but after all, it's not as if there are no nested conditions in many LaTeX macros... ;)

Comment: Too bad, thanks. So what is the recommanded solution? @lukeflo the main issue of nesting conditions is that I need to duplicate code, like `if a {if b {code A} else {code B}} else {code B}`. And every workaround to code duplication feels like a hack.

Comment: You could use a temporary boolean to record the result and then execute the code conditionally after the first `if ...` is finished.

Comment: @cfr ok, then I’m doing it the good way, thanks! (actually I test if a macro is defined… but I guess it is close enough)

Comment: @tobiasBora I find booleans easier to reuse but, indeed, I don't think the difference matters.

Comment: @cfr make sense. I just do that because it is one of the rare command I can remember :-P